# HTML5 video element — alternative text

Tags: html, html5-video

Unlike the `img` element, the `video` element doesn’t include an `alt` attribute for missing or inaccessible content. It seems to me that video is more likely to cause loading or accessibility problems than the humble image.

The note in the [W3C Document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-video-element) Doesn’t make make clear a simple alternative.

Is there a recommended procedure for providing a suitable alternative text, or, say a link to a transcript?

Comment: have you looked at adding ARIA attributes to the content, and using javascript handlers to trap any loading errors

Answer (score 5):

As you pointed out, the tag `<video>` doesn't have an `alt` attribute.

I have two ideas to satisfy at least in part this need.

**1) Adding a paragraph inside the `<video>` tag**

```
<video>
  <source src="my-video-path.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <p>Description of the video...</p>
</video>
```

**2) Adding [schema data](https://schema.org/VideoObject)**

```
<video itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject">
    <source src="my-video-path.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Name of the video">
    <meta itemprop="description" content="Description of the video...">
    <meta itemprop="duration" content="PT1M33S">
    <meta itemprop="thumbnail" content="my-video-thumbnail-path.jpg">
</video>
```

Comment: Any non-`<source>` and non-`<track>` content inside the `<video>` tag should *only* be a replacement for the video and *not* supplemental to it — it’s only intended for browsers that don’t support the video element. (kindof like `<noscript>`.) The [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#the-video-element) even says “this content is not intended to address accessibility concerns.”